# ext js row expander date format rendering

Tags: javascript, date, extjs, extjs4.2

I need to display 4 different date fields on my grid.
2 of them will be displayed directly as columns and all of them will be visible when row is expanded.

I am using ExtJS 4.2.1

Grid shows date in the format i want (like 27-12-2013 11:30)  but i cannot make expanded area to show formatted date.

- I tried to add renderer to model fields
- I tried to add dateFormat / dateReadFormat + dateWriteFormat
- If i dont add type as date it writes    java format, otherwise
  standard date format like Fri Dec 20 2013    11:51:00 GMT+0200 (GTB
  Standard Time)

I add dates to Json from java as follows.

```
if(account.getCreated() != null)
                accountJson.put("created", new  SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm").format(account.getCreated()));

            if(account.getModified() != null)
                accountJson.put("modified", new  SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm").format(account.getModified()));

            if(account.getBeginDate() != null)
                accountJson.put("beginDate", new  SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm").format(account.getBeginDate()));

            if(account.getEndDate() != null)
                accountJson.put("endDate", new  SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm").format(account.getEndDate()));
```

My ext js fields:

```
........
{name: "created", type: 'date'},
{name: "modified", type: 'date'},
{name: "beginDate", type: 'date'},
{name: "endDate", type: 'date'}
```

Grid columns:

```
{text: 'Başlangıç Tarihi',      sortable: true, dataIndex: 'beginDate', renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('d-m-Y H:i')},
{text: 'Bitiş Zamanı',          sortable: true, dataIndex: 'endDate', renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('d-m-Y H:i')}
```

rowexpander - rowBodyTpl:

```
'<table class="infoTable">' +  
                "<tr><th>Oluşturma Tarihi</th><td>{created}</td><th>Başlangıç Tarihi</th><td>{beginDate}</td></tr>" + 
                "<tr><th>Değiştirme Tarihi</th><td>{modified}</td><th>Bitiş Tarihi</th><td>{endDate}</td></tr>" + 
             "</table>"
```

**To show what I mean, here are some screenshots**

[image: image of the grid column date data]

[image: image of the expanded area.. sorry for bad marking]

Here in the 2nd picture you can also see that I need to convert some int values to String as well. I tried to send them to a function like **..Tpl of Expanded... " + myFormatter("{beginDate}") + " ... Tpl of Expanded cont.....**  but this doesnt work either:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method to reformat dates is `date` from `Ext.util.Format`.  Example:

`Ext.util.Format.date( myDateValue, 'm/d/Y' );`

Additionally, i believe renderer should be function:

```
renderer: function(value){
        return Ext.util.Format.date( value, 'm/d/Y' );;
    }
```

**Another option** could be to modify the value in the `Ext.data.Model` `field`. `Ext.data.Field` has a `config` option `convert`.

```
{ name: "createdStringFormat", convert: function (value, record) {
            var created = record.data.created;
            //convert created to string rep you want
            var createdString = '';
            createdString = Ext.util.Format.date(created, 'm/d/Y');
            return createdString;
        }
}
```

You could either convert the value on the specific field or add another field with the converted value.

Comment: `Ext.util.Format.date` formats mirror php's date function.  Please see link for available formats. [PHP Date Formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: Ext.util.Format.date works fine for columns of the grid but I still cannot edit the format in expanded area. I even tried to add a function that uses util format and call it in expanded part like .... + myFormatter("{beginDate}") + .... but that doesnt work either. And it is not just the date, I have other data to be formatted (like int values to strings as in a combobox)

Comment: you could also maybe use convert on field in model to create addl/modify existing field with the format you require?  Added to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I created a new field for formatted version as I need to keep original form of the data for comboboxes and other things. It still gives error when trying to convert the original date field but it is probably my mistake somewhere, it works fine for new fields.